# Orange3 txt files don't seem to work with logistic regression

Tags: text, logistic-regression, corpus, orange

I just started working with Orange3 doing text analytics.  When I create a corpus made up of .txt files I can get the workflow to function where I can generate a word cloud and I can view the corpus on the corpus viewer, but if I want to do a logistic regression on the bag of words it always throws an error that reads "Data has no target variable" and it won't run that widget.

The corpus that works that is preloaded in Orange3 is .TAB and when I attempt to save all the .txt documents to a spreadsheet (one document per line) it still won't recognize the files.